# Why did Lucifer interfere with Mammon crossing over?

Tags: dc, constantine-2005, constantine

Why did Lucifer care about Mammon crossing over from Hell to the real world?  Before coming up to drag John (literally) to Hell, he makes a detour and sends his son back to presumably prevent Hell on earth.  Why would the master of Hell not want to expand his domain?

Comment: If you are the ruler of some world, would you want your subordinates to start their own empire somewhere else without you telling them to?

Answer (score 12):

From [the script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Constantine.html)

> MIDNITE
>
> Mammon has been trying to climb
>   out of his father's shadow for
>   eons.
>
> JOHN
>
> And this time he might just make
>   it.
>
> MIDNITE
>
> (unconvinced)
>   Because he's got the Spear?
>
> JOHN
>
> And the bridge.

And later...

> JOHN
>
> ... so how's your son?
>
> SATAN
>
> And why would that matter to you?
>
> JOHN
>
> ... he's topside...
>
> SATAN
>
> I know.
>
> JOHN
>
> With Gabriel.
>
> SATAN
>
> Your point?
>
> JOHN
>
> He's helping your son create his
>   own Hell on Earth...
>
> SATAN
>
> Well, boys will be boys...
>
> JOHN
>
> He has the Spear of Destiny.
>
> Satan didn't know that. Now he's concerned. He studies
>   this dying man.

It's not really clearly spelled out, but it seems as though Satan's pride won't let him have anyone outdoing him or anyone else creating hell on Earth - not even his own son.

Answer (score 6):

When Angela Dodson visits Constantine in his home, then leaves and Constantine follows her (approximately 36 minutes into the movie), he says the following:

> **Constantine** What if I told you that God and the Devil made a wager? A kind of standing bet for the souls of all mankind
>
> **Dodson** I'd tell you to stay on your meds
>
> **Constantine** Humor me. No direct contact with humans, that would be the rule. Just influence, see who would win.
>
> **Dodson** Okay, I'm humoring you. Why?
>
> **Constantine** Who knows? Maybe just for the fun of it, no telling.

When Lucifer comes along later on and saves Dodson from Gabriel, he says

> **Lucifer** This world is mine, in time.

So two reasons here: He wants to win his bet with God, and he wants to stop Mammon from taking over the world, which he considers to be his.

Answer (score 0):

He told his son Mammon before he sent him back that all the souls on earth will be his "in time"; if he allowed him to make hell on earth that would prevent any new souls in hell ...